# Bootstrap card header: div class= card-header card-header-warning

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, dashboard, card

I face a problem while using some bootstrap card on one page by copying and pasting exactly the same code because I want to show both cards are the same.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card card-chart">
      <div class="card-header card-header-warning">
        <div class="ct-chart" id="websiteViewsChart"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Policies</h4>
        <p class="card-category"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <p>Policies Graph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card card-chart">
      <div class="card-header card-chart card-header-warning">
        <div class="ct-chart" id="websiteViewsChart"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Policies</h4>
        <p class="card-category"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="stats">
          <p>Policies Graph</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first one is displaying and the second one is missing some design, please look at the code and the output too, I will be glad if you answer me thank you.
[image]

Comment: The bootstrap looks fine. You have duplicate id for both chart. `websiteViewsChart` Please change that for the second chart to render

Answer (score 0):

I review the code bellow, and add flex command to center both cards + dummy images to replace the chart that is included in picture but not in code.
The finnal code is the following

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <div class="card card-chart">
            <div class="card-header card-header-warning">
                <div class="ct-chart text-center" id="websiteViewsChart">
                    <img  src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="Rock And Roll">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Policies</h4>
                <p class="card-category"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="stats">
                    <p>Policies Graph</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" >
        <div class="card card-chart">
            <div class="card-header card-chart card-header-warning">
                <div class="ct-chart text-center" id="websiteViewsChart">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" alt="Rock And Roll">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Policies</h4>
                <p class="card-category"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="stats">
                    <p>Policies Graph</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```